# python makes ssl crash

Tags: python, ssl, bitcoin

The following script causes segmentation fault on my laptop:

```
import ctypes
from bitcoin.core.key import NID_secp256k1
ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library ('ssl') or 'libeay32')
ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1), 0)
```

This piece of code comes from python-bitcoinlib (https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib).
I have not opened a ticket to the project itself as the crash comes from the **i2o_ECPublicKey** external function from libcrypto.so.1.0.0.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, libcrypto.so.1.0.0, python 3.4. I have also tried with python 2, with the very same result, as I expected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 'libeay32' is a Windows SSL library, so you don't need that on Linux. What does this print: `python -c "from ctypes.util import find_library;print find_library('ssl')"`? If it prints `None`, change `'ssl'` to `'crypto'` and try again. You can do SSL stuff using `libcrypto.so`, but IIRC it's better to use `libssl.so`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I get 'libssl.so.1.0.0'. Unfortunately, I get the same result with 'crypto' library.

Comment: See if your script runs when you replace line 3 with `ssl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libssl.so")`. If that doesn't work, try `ssl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libcrypto.so")`

Comment: In order to make that change, I had to specify the full path of the library. The final line of code was 
    ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so')

Unfortunately, I got the same result...

Comment: Hmmm. It's odd that it needs the full path of the lib. The rationale for that stuff I asked you to run before was to check that ctypes is loading the lib that you expect it to, just in case using the wrong lib is the reason for the segfault. Disclaimer: I have used libssl.so via ctypes but I'm certainly not an expert in using either ctypes or openssl. But the code above looks a bit fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the OpenSSL docs for [i2o_ECPublicKey()](http://openssl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.0d-2/crypto_2ec_2ec_8h_a1a93f5739c093586ef83517b52b44a0c.html). Those docs are for C programmers, but they still contain useful info for Python programmers (but I admit it helps if you know C :) ).

As those docs state, the 2nd arg to `i2o_ECPublicKey()` should be a pointer to the output buffer; if you pass `NULL` as the 2nd arg to `i2o_ECPublicKey()` it just returns the number of bytes needed for the output buffer; you should save that return value so you can re-call `i2o_ECPublicKey` with a properly initialised buffer of the correct size. To pass `NULL` using Python ctypes you need to use `None`. I ***suspect*** that passing `0` to a lib function that expects a pointer may confuse things, with disastrous results.

So substitute this for the above code:

```
import ctypes
from bitcoin.core.key import NID_secp256k1
ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so')
eckey = ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)
keysize = ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(eckey, None)
```

and see if that avoids the segfault. If it works, you can use [create_string_buffer(keysize)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) to initialise the actual output buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am sorry I got the very same result. The only combination that does not crash is specifying 0 as the first parameter...
Currently I am trying to invoke that API in a C program. Unfortunately I am not a C programmer and I am experiencing many problems...

Comment: So `eckey = ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)` works ok? Maybe you need to pass that key back to the lib using `byref()`, eg `keysize = ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(byref(eckey), None)`

Comment: Yes, the `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name function` works perfectly and returns an int. 
Unfortunately `eckey` is an int, not a a ctypes instance. Maybe I should convert eckey to a pointer (the C API declare to return an `EC_KEY*` which is a pointer). 
The following line, though, does not seem to work:

`ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(ctypes.cast(eckey, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)), None)`

Comment: So `byref(eckey)` didn't work? Is `eckey` an `int` or it it really a pointer to an `ec_key_st` structure...?

Comment: `byref(eckey)` does not work as it complains saying that it is expecting a ctypes type (`TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'`). `eckey` seems to be an integer (`type(eckey)` prints 'int').

Comment: From [15.17.1.8. Return types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types): By default functions are assumed to return the C int type. Other return types can be specified by setting the restype attribute of the function object.

Comment: @fcracker79 has this been resolved? I'm trying to overcome the same issue as you, but the OS is Win7 x64 (Ubuntu 14LTS through a VM); `if _ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(_NID_secp256k1) == 0:` raises an OS error: `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x100FA4F4`... *Logs*: [PasteBin](https://gist.github.com/924cf9892e097df03937) / [Imgur](http://imgur.com/iIAW0wN). **To clarify that mess:** what was the end result?

Comment: @Aussie: sorry I did not solve the problem. Currently I am using a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into problems with these libraries on Windows. Eventually ended up using `python-bitcoinrpc` library instead. That one worked nicely out of the box.